# How to load Obj with associating MTL (texture) in C#

Tags: c#, textures, helix-3d-toolkit

I try to load obj with the mtl(textures).
I am using helixtoolkit

```
        ObjReader CurrentHelixObjReader = new ObjReader();
        objmodel.Content = CurrentHelixObjReader.Read(@"C:...");
```

.obj works but always grey

The .mtl file is in the same folder.

Anyone clue how to realize this ...

Answer (score 0):

The way I load .obj files using Helix is as follows.

First, I create a **ModelImporter** object. A ModelImporter object handles the loading of a model from a file.

Then, I simply call the *Load* method of the new ModelImporter object, passing the filepath of the .obj file I want to import as a string. The *Load* method returns a *Model3DGroup*, so I capture the returned value in a Model3DGroup object.

```
ModelImporter importer = new ModelImporter(); 

Model3DGroup group = importer.Load(filePath);
```

That's all there is to it. The *Load* method of the ModelImporter handles correctly importing the .obj file. There is logic within the method to determine what file you're trying to import, so you don't necessarily need to worry about that yourself.

As for the .mtl file, so long as the .mtl file is in the same directory as the .obj file, HelixToolkit should handle that for you as well. I didn't have to do anything else to get it to work.

Comment: Could you give an example of your xaml? I am using the same code as you described above, but the object always has a default color.